# SVG lines not visible

Tags: css, html

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/a0hj0j9s/)

```
<svg version="1.1">
  <line x1="492" y1="503" x2="717" y2="576" stroke="#4A4A4A" stroke-width="2"></line>
  <line x1="500" y1="400" x2="600" y2="400" stroke="#4A4A4A" stroke-width="2"></line>
  <line x1="604.5" y1="539.5" x2="587.5" y2="542.5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"></line>
  <line x1="604.5" y1="539.5" x2="592.5" y2="527.5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"></line>
</svg>
```

If I give x1="0" and y1="0" then the lines become visible.
Why is the line not visible in the code above?

Comment: because your svg has no size (nor even viewbox attribute) and because your lines are off screen area probably

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add width and height to svg element (make sure that is big enough to cover your drawing)

```
<svg version="1.1" width="1000" height="1000">
  <line x1="492" y1="503" x2="717" y2="576" stroke="#4A4A4A" stroke-width="2"></line>
  <line x1="500" y1="400" x2="600" y2="400" stroke="#4A4A4A" stroke-width="2"></line>
  <line x1="604.5" y1="539.5" x2="587.5" y2="542.5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"></line>
  <line x1="604.5" y1="539.5" x2="592.5" y2="527.5" stroke="red" stroke-width="2"></line>
</svg>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/af5g1d3q/

Comment: MDN's documentation for SVG [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/height) and [width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/width) explain why this is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I hit this same confusion because I had supplied `fill`, but not `stroke` to my lines. Adding a `stroke` attribute made them visible.